# i can't insert form-data to db using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

so i tried to debug via (dd), and the result is: the $request is giving the right data before the validation.
But when i try to do the same thing after the validation it show nothing, and it dosen't even get to the line after the end of the validation ( validate([..]); ).
#web route
`Route::post('/application/apply' , [applicationController::class , 'create']);`

#app controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\application;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class applicationController extends Controller
{

  public function create(Request $request) {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'block_no' => 'required',
            'home_number' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'jop' => 'required',
            'old_jop' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'm_status' => 'required',
            'children_count' => 'required',
            'teeth_coverage' => 'required',
            'vision_coverage' => 'required',
            'pregnancy_coverage' => 'required',
        ]);
        application::create($formFields);
        return rediredct('/');
    }
}
```

#application model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class application extends Model
{
    use HasFactory ,Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name' ,
         'city' ,
         'address' ,
         'block_no' ,
         'home_number',
         'phone_number' ,
          'email' ,
          'jop' ,
          'old_jop' ,
          'company' ,
          'm_status' ,
          'children_count' ,
          'teeth_coverage' ,
          'vision_coverage' ,
           'pregnancy_coverage',
        ];
}
```

#I tested the $request, and it's functioning well

```
 public function create(Request $request) {
        dd($request);
```

#I tested the $formFields (the form input), but i getno response.

```
    'pregnancy_coverage' => 'required',
        ]);`your text``your text`
        dd($formFields);
        application::create($formFields);
        return rediredct('/');
    }
}
```

#what am i missing?

Comment: Maybe the validation fails so a redirection happens.

Comment: it dosen't redirect

Comment: Just an observation, you are misspelling redirect `return rediredct('/');`.